# Javascript / jquery - click() method on <a> tag or href value

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a third party site I want to click on the following link to open a modal. 
`<a data-login-modal href=/login class="link-reset">`

I was thinking using the `.click()` method.

Yet I'm in trouble because that `<a>` :

- does not have `ID` - so I can't use `$(#id).click()`;
- does not have a unique class - so I can't use `$(.class).click()`;

What is the proper way to use the `.click()` method on the basis of the `href` or the `<a>` name `(data-login-modal)` ?

Comment: Try using code formatting, it's fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the following solutions:

```
$("a[href='your_href_link']").click(function(){
//body
})
```

**OR**

```
$("a[name='data-login-modal']").click(function(){
//body
})
```

Comment: I'll go with that answer as using the href is the only way I can make it work. The `$("a[name='data-login-modal']").click(function(){
//body
})` doest not work in the chrome javascript console, it just returns an empty array [ ]

Answer (score 2):

To get an element by name in jQuery:

```
$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').click();
```

Or more specifically for your requirement:

```
$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').click(function () {
   // do stuff
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mtgr2df/).

Comment: Cannot make work either of this two way in the Chrome console.. only the href way proposed by @Rajan works, don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="your_href_link"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // preventing normal href!
});
```

Without preventDefault(), the href will also be executed!

Further, it's not a nice approach to select based on href. Not really maintainable because links are often dynamic. I suggests you to use id's, classes or data-attributes.